# Shader Variable Types

Tags: opengl, directx, shaders, glsl, hlsl

I have a simple question. what are the meaning of :

```
half4 myHalf;
myHalf.yyyy;
myHalf.xxzz;
// or
myHalf.yw
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple answer! `half4` is a four component vector, using half precision floating point coordinates. The extensions you've shown are quick ways to create new vectors using the values from `myHalf`.

`myHalf.yyyy` is a four component vector with the values:
     `(myhalf.y, myhalf.y, myhalf.y, myhalf.y)`

`myHalf.xxzz` is a four component vector with the values:
     `(myhalf.x, myhalf.x, myhalf.z, myhalf.z)`

`myHalf.yw` is a two component vector with the values:
     `(myhalf.y, myhalf.w)`.

Comment: This is also referring to as "[swizzling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219869(v=vs.85).aspx)".